# Textbox Controlling a Query Field

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have to manage various outfalls for stormwater discharge. The issue is that there are various names that have to me used and maintained. Because of this when the reports are generated they have to use the naming convention requested by the client.

First I created a table with the following fields:
outfall_ID
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5

The table may have more names in the future but for now 5 is the maximum I am dealing with

I then created a form which acts as a setup form allowing the user to select name1 through name5 identifying the current name needed for the report.

Here's the part where I am having issues.
In the query I bring in the outfall table and I can choose the ID and the Name fields. but I only want to have the name field active that matches the text field in the setup form (which the information is stored in a table for referencing).

Nothing I have tried or looked up has worked

Answer (score 0):

You can’t really desing a form that works with columns name1 to name5.

Access is a database, not a spreadsheet. So when working with data, you work with rows of data, not columns of data.

So make a table that holds the names you want to select.

Outfall_ID  |   Name.

Your table will have two columns like above. You can then build a form, and drive a combo box (or listbox) that is based on the above table. That will present a list or combo box that allows you to select the name.

On this form, below the combo box (or listbox), you then have a button to launch your report. You can filter the report by the selected name like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptOutfalls", acViewPreview, , "outfall_ID = " & Me.MyComboBox
```

The above will filter the report by the given (selected) outfall_ID.

If you need to filter the report by the actual text name you select in the combo box (or list box), we assume that the combo box displays both outfall_id, and the name. So the name is the second columd of the combo box.

If we are to filter the reports by the selected name, then the openreprot command will look like:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptOutfalls", acViewPreview, , "outfallName = '" & Me.MyComboBox.column(1) & "'"
```

So the above report will now only filter to the name you selected in the combo box.

## Edit

Edit:
SQL can’t translate columns to diffent columns. You need to normailize the data, so such updates can be done with SQL.

Your table will thus have to look like this:

```
mytrans
ID  Myset   SetID   TranslateTo
1   Name1   1   A
2   Name1   2   B
3   Name1   3   C
4   Name2   1   X
5   Name2   2   Y
6   Name2   3   X
```

Your combo box will thus be based on this query:

```
select distinct MySet from myTrans
```

Your sql to “translate” the ID based on above would then be

```
Select ID, Field1, Field2, outfall_ID,
 (select TranslateTo from mytrans 
    where mytrans.SetID = outfall_id and myset = 'Name1’) as outfallText
 from theDataTable
```

Comment: @ Albert What you are suggesting makes sense in most cases but the issue arises from the use of the various names.

I dont need a combo box to show me the various names. I need a query that will switch table fields when referencing a control on the setup form. 

    Example:
    `Outfall ID:
    1
    2
    3`

`Name1: A B C`
`Name2: X Y Z`

If the control says `Name1` then I want to use `A B C` and if the control says `Name2` then I want to use `X Y Z`

The idea was to have the control change and then have the query pull that change into itself and update